# Laravel post data through api routes throws 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to send data with ajax (using axios for that) through an api to my controller.
First of all my routes file (/routes/api.php):

```
Route::post('/booking/request', 'BookingController@sendMail');
```

I want to send data to this route, so here is my request for that:

```
var bookingUrl = baseUrl + 'api/booking/request';

axios.post(bookingUrl, {
    name: "username",
    amount: 2
});
```

And after that, I just want to log this data to see if it got to my controller (app/Http/Controllers/BookingController):

```
class BookingController extends Controller
{
    public function sendMail(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('data: ' . $request->name);

    }
}
```

This doesn't work at all. I just get an error "404 Not Found". I also tried this request with Postman, but same results. Since I can't get more information about what exactly isn't working, I can't fix it. Can someone get me on the right path here?

Edit: So the actual problem was the baseUrl. There was a wrong link behind, so it couldn't work.

Comment: What is `bookingUrl` set to? Check `php artisan routes:list` to make sure it matches.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post. bookingUrl is set to `baseUrl + 'api/booking/request'`. And php artisan routes:list is showing an entry for my route  `POST | api/booking/request | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@sendMail | api`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but try `public function sendMail(Request $request)` for the definition, and inside `Log::info($request->name);`

Comment: I think your attempt is the right way for that part, but it still doesn't work. I also think I don't even get to the controller. The mistake must be somwhere before that.

Answer (score 2):

axios.post is just a post request, not an API specific request.
Put you route declaration in routes/web.php file

```
//web.php
// now the url for post request will be /booking/request
Route::post('/booking/request', 'BookingController@sendMail');
```

and in js

```
//JS
var bookingUrl = baseUrl + 'booking/request';

axios.post(bookingUrl, {
    name: "username",
    amount: 2
});
```

If you still need **api** prefix, add api in route declaration

```
Route::post('/api/booking/request', 'BookingController@sendMail');

// or

Route::group(['prefix'=>'api'], function(){
    Route::post('/booking/request', 'BookingController@sendMail');
});
```

Comment: Same result. I also have a few get requests which are working fine with axios.get. Shouldn't they work neither if they're not API specific?

Comment: This still doesn't solve my problem. I also read up on routes in the api file and that part should be correct the I did it, because in [RouteServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L74) it adds the api middleware to routes in the api-route file.

Comment: Then you should check your **baseurl** variable in axios request

Comment: @kk_: re: your now-deleted answer that the problem was `baseUrl` outside the code in the question:  If that totally invalidates the main question, you should either delete it or rewrite it so Abid's answer works as a code-review or something.